Firebase doesn't auto-renew SSL for hosting
My project is hosted on Firebase with an Advanced setup mode (using A records instead of CNAME). I ensured not to delete the _acme-challenge. Additionally, I have Cloudflare configured with SSL set to Full (it was previously Strict) and SSL/TLS Recommender enabled.
However, every three months, the SSL certificate expires, forcing me to remove the domain from Firebase and reconfigure everything. This process results in the website being down for a few hours.
Currently, Firebase indicates a "Need setup" status again, meaning the SSL will likely go down in a couple of days. Yesterday, I disabled the proxy on Cloudflare, hoping it would resolve the issue, but unfortunately, it didn't work.


Cloudflare


